# Moving Element from top to bottom with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I want to move an element from top to bottom, adding 1px to its top every 10millisecond using `setInterval`

This is my code:

```js
var cir1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cir1');

function moveCir(elem) {
    var elemTop = elem.style.top + 'px';
    elem.style.top = elemTop;
    elem.style.top = elemTop + 1 + 'px' ;
    setInterval(function () {
        moveCir(elem)
    },10)
}
```

```css
.cir1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 30px 100px;
    border: 1px solid #AC0D67;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="moveCir(cir1)" id="start">Start</button>
<div class="cir1"></div>
```

But I cant find out why its not working

Comment: Please provide a m-c-v-e -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Not working how?

Comment: when I click on start button the div doesn't move

Comment: I think you have to remove the "px" at the end before incremeting it

Comment: Your **first** problem is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: Another problem might be (depending on how the whole html is set up) that in: `moveCir(cir1)` `cir1` might be undefined.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName returns an array so u have to do document.getElementsByClassName('cir1')[0];

Comment: Also recursively calling `setInterval` will result break sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you want this:

```js
function moveCir(elem) {
  var elemTop = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if (elemTop < 200) {
    elem.style.top = elemTop + 1 + 'px';
    setTimeout(function() {
      moveCir(elem)
    }, 100)
  }
}
```

```css
#cir1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 30px 100px;
  border: 1px solid #AC0D67;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="moveCir(cir1)" id="start">Start</button>
<div id="cir1"></div>
```

however,i have to warn you :

this is a bad idea :

```
onclick="moveCir(cir1)"
```

a better solution is here:

```js
var moveCir = function f(elem) {
  var elemTop = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if (elemTop < 200) {
    cir1.style.top = elemTop + 1 + 'px';
    setTimeout(f, 100, elem);
  }
};

var cir1 = document.getElementById('cir1');
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function() {
  moveCir(cir1)
}, false);
```

```css
#cir1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 30px 100px;
  border: 1px solid #AC0D67;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<div id="cir1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cir = document.getElementsByClassName('cir1')[0];
var cirTop = cir.style.top;
function moveCir() {
cirTop++;
cir.style.top = cirTop + 'px';
}
setInterval(moveCir, 10);
```

class names are taken as an array. You have not included [0] in `document.getElementsByClassName('cir1')`